# Geo-Availability Single Terminal Server Opinions

Tags: azure, terminal-server, infrastructure

First off, I am not an Azure specialist by any means, but I do have experience with creating Azure VM's for site to cloud replication and stand-alone cloud environments for business solutions.

Recently, I been tasked with proposing a solution for a global company who will need access to a terminal server in the cloud from many parts of the globe. Included areas are South Africa, Vietnam, Asia, European countries, south America, and the USA. Now, I know Azure has servers around the world, but I am unclear to whether or not to create multiple terminal servers for access, or if there is a feature that I can replicate the server across different geo locations for performance. Or if anyone has any input as to what would be best practices for providing a terminal server that needs to be accessed from many different locations.

Can I replicate a single terminal server across multiple data centers in azure?

Basically I am in need of a way to make an Azure terminal server performance solid no matter where someone remotes in from. I know RDP protocol in general is very solid with minimal bandwidth requirements, but want to ensure this is a proper solution for my client.

To add, I understand that Azure may not be the best solution. In a perfect work I would have different domains across multiple locations, but I am trying to leverage the cloud as a possible solution to prevent a management nightmare for this company, especially considering their budget is not very large.

End goal is to get them in a Microsoft environment, and remove google drive as their go to for storage and access to documents for their entire business.

Thanks all.

Comment: `End goal is to get them in a Microsoft environment, and remove google drive as their go to for storage and access to documents for their entire business.` Geo-located RDS servers seems like an odd way to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to Azure RemoteApp which is an RDP service in azure as opposed to your own VM running terminal services. The only advantage you'll get by having RD RemoteApp in different data centres is the slightly better connectivity to the local Azure data centre.  Azure RemoteApp is resilient by itself, so my advice start in the data centre closest to the most users and scale out if performance is an issue.  This you you'll only have one image to manage update with your applications